# Is there any method to approximate or simplify this equation?

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, approximation

I have a question. Is there any method to simplify or approximate this formula? I have never studied two trigonometric functions used at the same time, so I don't know how to approach this right now.

Formula is following:

$$\exp(-\cot(\arcsin(\frac{RS^2-RE^2}{2*r*RE} - \frac{r}{2*RE}))) $$

Here RS and RE is just constant, actually RE is radius of earth and RS is a circular orbit which is always larger than $RE (RS>RE)$. only 'r' is variable here. To be very precise, 'r' is only definable for $[R_{\min},R_{\max}]$ but I don't think this is important right now.

The problem is as I wrote, I don't have any clues or ideas to simplify/approximate this formula. Only thing I know is that the formula inside $\arcsin$ is always 0~1.

Can someone give me a hint for this? I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Hint: try to simplify your question. You've written a full expression out, with an exponential, a variable and two constants you haven't really asked about. I'd suggest you're really interested in "is there a way to simplify $\cot(\arcsin(X))$?" If that's the case, try drawing a right angled triangle with hypotenuse $1$ and one side $X$. Can you work out the ratio you need?

Comment: Actually I tried it just before I post it, but it changes to sqrt(1-x^2)/x, but if I consider x is that formula inside arcsin, this made the situation worse so I tried to ask it to StackExchange.. but thanks for your hint :)

Comment: That's a bit of a matter of opinion. It's possibly more compact to write it the way you have it in your question, but also you have two trig functions in there. You'll find things cancel a lot if you work it through. A better form to use is probably $\cot\left(\arcsin{\frac{A}{B}}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{B^2-A^2}}{A}$

Comment: Thanks for advice sir, I'll try it through again!

Comment: @AmsaJYP From both numerical and performance viewpoints the simplification using algebraic terms suggested by Chris Lewis is much preferred; for the accurate computation of $\sqrt{B^2-A^2}$ see also this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191477/companion-to-hypot) on Stackoverflow.